# Angular 6 - Use component props as same component attribute value

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component that is passing props down to a child component. I would like to take the resulting value of `[info]` and use it as my condition for `[value]`

Basically, is the `[info]` prop equal to the String `good-info` ? If yes, set value to `Happy` otherwise set it to `Sad`

```
<some-component [info]="row.calculation.anotherCalculation.information"
                [value]="info === 'good-info' ? 'Happy' : 'Sad' "
></some-component >
```

Of course I could use the same calculation for `value` that I'm using for `info` but that seems redundant. Also the calculation used in the `info` prop is much longer than the example one shown above.

Comment: Can't you calculate the info value at parent component init method and use it?

Comment: I guess it depends, parent might not have knowledge of how value is computed. a callback can be passed around, but that is more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the child component with a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) (e.g. `#child`), which will allow you to get the value of the `info` property. However, the code below causes an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` because one property depends on the other being set in the same detection cycle.

```
<some-component #child 
  [info]="row.calculation.anotherCalculation.information"
  [value]="child.info === 'good-info' ? 'Happy' : 'Sad' ">
</some-component >
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7hfxgu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

---

The exception mentioned above can be avoided if you set `value` when a change event is triggered from the child component after `info` has been set:

```
export class SomeComponent {

  private _info: string;

  @Output() infoChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();

  @Input() public get info(): string {
    return this._info;
  }
  public set info(x: string) {
    this._info = x;
    this.infoChanged.emit(x);
  }

  @Input() public value: string;
}
```

```
<some-component #child 
  [info]="row.calculation.anotherCalculation.information" 
  (infoChanged)="child.value = $event === 'good-info' ? 'Happy' : 'Sad'" >
</some-component>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjov6y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Comment: I think this is the purest solution to solve the question asked. Not sure how recommended it is, as I don't see this strategy much - thank you

Comment: A component referring to itself is used quite commonly. However, I see that trying to set value from info in the same change detection cycle causes an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` in development mode. I added a second method to the answer to avoid the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a method doing your calculations (in this example only returning the nested attribute), something like

```js
class SomeComponent {
    calculate(row: any) {
        return row.calculation.anotherCalculation.information;
    }
}
```

Then, in your HTML you can do

```html
<div *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <some-component [info]="calculate(row)"
                    [value]="calculate(row) === 'good-info' ? 'Happy' : 'Sad' "
    ></some-component>
</div>
```

Comment: In my case, for example - `row` is in a loop, inside my template and will change well after the component has been initialized. I guess, you're somewhat suggesting for each row iteration - call a function to from the template to do the calculation, instead of doing the calculation in the template

Comment: Okay, if you are in a loop I would simply suggest using a function that wraps your calculations, and call it in each place in the template. I updated my answer.

Comment: Right. I was trying to avoid this as I'll have to change a good amount of the app code, but I think this is the "proper" solution. Thanks